# How to access a service from another namespace in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have the zipkin deployment and service below as you can see zipkin is located under monitoring namespace the, i have an env variable called **ZIPKIN_URL** in each of my pods which are running under default namespace, this varibale takes this URL **http://zipkin:9411/api/v2/spans** but since zipkin is running in another namespace i tried this :

http://zipkin.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:9411/api/v2/spans

i also tried this format :

http://zipkin.monitoring:9411/api/v2/spans

but when i check the logs of my pods, i see **connection refused exception**

when i exec into one of my pods and try curl http://zipkin.tools.svc.cluster.local:9411/api/v2/spans

its shows me **Mandatory parameter is missing: serviceNameroot**

Here is zipkin resource :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zipkin
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zipkin
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: zipkin
        image: openzipkin/zipkin:2.19.3
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9411

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zipkin
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    app: zipkin
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 9411
      protocol: TCP
  type: ClusterIP
```

Comment: Do you have a different `targetPort`? Did you check the network policies?

Comment: yes i had checked it everything is well configured

Comment: I don't think this is a namespace issue. What happens if you perform the curl from within the zipkin pod or another pod in the same namespace?

Comment: i did lookup on http://zipkin.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:9411 it works fine but when i try http://zipkin.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:9411/api/v2/spans it tells me : Mandatory parameter is missing: serviceName

Answer (score 0):

What you have is correct, your issue is likely not DNS. You can confirm by doing just a DNS lookup and comparing that to the IP of the Service.

Comment: i did lookup on http://zipkin.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:9411 it works fine but when i try http://zipkin.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:9411/api/v2/spans it tells me : Mandatory parameter is missing: serviceName

Comment: It looks like the error message you get is not form kubernetes but from zipkin API you're trying to make a call to and it looks like such a call to be successful requires some additional parameters. If you are still able to hit `zipkin.monitoring.svc.cluster.local:9411` from a `Pod` located in another namespace, I would say there is no issue with accessing kubernetes `Service` from another namespace at all.